# Calculating income and expenses per month

Tags: django

Hello developers How to  calculate income with date .For example income of last month income of last year and income of this month.

models.py

```
class Add(models.Model):
    income = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    expense = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: What have your tried? Have you read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/aggregation/)?

Comment: No did not read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`TruncMonth`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#django.db.models.functions.TruncMonth) to truncate the `date` to the start of the month. Then we can annotate that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Add.objects.annotate(
    month=TruncMonth('date')
).values('month').annotate(
    total_income=Sum('income'),
    total_expense=Sum('expense')
).order_by('month')
```

This will return a `QuerySet` that wraps dictionaries, for example:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'month': datetime(2019, 1, 1), 'total_income': 123, 'total_expense': 456},
    {'month': datetime(2019, 2, 1), 'total_income': 450, 'total_expense': 321}
]>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'truncates' functions, like TruncMonth, TruncDay, TruncYear ( [...see doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#datetimefield-truncation)).
Code Example:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
from django.db.models import Sum

Add.objects
    .annotate(month=TruncMonth('date'))  # Truncate to month and add to select list
    .values('month')                          # Group By month
    .annotate(income_sum=Sum('income'),expense_sum=Sum('expense'))                  # Select the count of the grouping
    .values('month', 'income_sum','expense_sum')
```